# How to handle >1000 character lines in 8bit mime

Tags: email, smtp, mime, 8-bit

When using 8BITMIME smtp, you can set Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit in Mime messages and send text without encoding.

Except, there is still a line limit of 1000 octets (plus the line endings should all be `<CR><LF>`)

When my library gets arbitrary UTF-8 data from a user, how should I go about splitting lines? Is there any way to split a 1002 octets line in a safe way? And what about a 1002 octet word (without whitespace).

In Quoted-Printable you can do `=<CR><LF>`, is there something similar for 8bit?

Comment: Note that the 1000 octet limit includes the CRLF, so that means your line limit is actually only 998 octets.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for `8bit` to have longer lines, just like there is no way for `7bit` to (legitimately) contain 8-bit characters.  If you want arbitrarily long lines, the `binary` content type is available, but the standard, robust approach is to use a content-transfer-encoding such as quoted-printable or base64.  Then the content within the encoding can be completely free-form.